# SaveChangesAsync deadlocks when used with different task in Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I want to save entity to the database and to xml log file in parallel.

`AddAsync` method inside my repository looks like this (and it works fine):

```
protected async Task<int> AddAsync(T entity)
{    
    using (var context = new myDbContext())
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Method which saves logs to xml file looks like this:

```
await _xmlDbHelper.Log(entity);
```

To run them in parallel I'm trying to do this:

```
List<Task<int>> taskArray = new List<Task<int>> {
    Task.Run(async () => await AddAsync(person)),
    Task.Run(async () => await _xmlDbHelper.Log(person))
};

await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
```

or

```
List<Task<int>> taskArray = new List<Task<int>> {
    AddAsync(person),
    _xmlDbHelper.Log(person)
};

await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
```

But `AddAsync` doesn't ever run. It stays in state of `WaitingForActivation` forever. Putting `AddAsync` alone in the array and never calling `_xmlDbHelper.Log` at all has the same effect.

Comment: You can't run multiple operations on the same context. Also, if your using EF then you shouldn't be using `AddAsync`.

Comment: @JSteward my bad, there was an error in my example code. I'v fixed it. _xmlDbHelper uses Log method, not AddAsync. Log (and the _xmlDbHelper in its entirety) dose not use contex.

Comment: Ok is anything blocking in the implementation of `Log(...)`? Or is `person`  coming from an open query?

Comment: @JSteward Log(..) uses xml serializer on passed object and saves resulting string it into a local file. As far I can tell there is nothing that should cause a block in there. Also I'v tried straight up commenting  out "_xmlDbHelper.Log(person)"  - doesn't help.